# What word describes random unfitting accusations

Tags: single-word-requests

I really dont know how to describe this. Im having a discussion with someone, I was sharing information that I found on a topic. Randomly im called out as being rude when nowhere was there evidence of rudeness exchanged. This person seems to have a history of claiming people have a problem or are being rude out of the random blue.

Is there a word to describe these random accusations that dont connect to anything?

Comment: Whoops I thought that meant i was looking for a single word to describe what im looking for. Its almost like slander I would think, except unintentional. Its like a problem in the persons mind causing them to think something so erratic.

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate and closed had the body question 'I like to have a friendly debate, but a lot of time people just come up with nonsense arguments like "Yeah but I'm right because you are stupid.". They are meant to be insults, but is there a word for this type of argument?'. An 'ad hominem' thrust ('attacking the person rather than the argument) is suggested.