# What word describes random unfitting judgements?

Tags: single-word-requests

- **Example 1:**

Person: Why are healthcare workers wearing masks if it wont protect us?

Me: Proper fitting N95 masks provide protection, others do not.

Person: Wow, why are you so rude?

Rudeness was not exchanged whatsoever.

- **Example 2:**

Person: Hey can you grab me the tool?

Me: Yes, here you are. *Gives tool without problem*

Person: Whats your problem today?!?

The situation did not have any acts of aggression.

Person is genuinely suddenly under an irrational belief that another is being rude with no supporting evidence presenting as rude or being a problem. I am looking for a word that describes a random unfitting judgement or claim that doesnt make sense. Imagine youre having a conversation with someone, and they respond with something completely unrelated leaving you scratching your head.

Not slander because they arent intentionally trying to demean you.
Not ad hominem because they arent attacking you instead of the conversation.

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528926/what-word-describes-random-unfitting-accusations)? Site policy is to edit the original, and then wait for re-open. Although this is a much better Q...it is possiby still too broad.

Comment: It was closed. Im sorry, im new here! I suppose that one can be deleted then if a mod sees it.

Comment: Let's wait and see. Good luck.

Comment: Over-sensitive? Defensive?

Comment: "Wow, why are you so rude?" / "What's your problem?!?" **are clear examples of being rude**, especially to a wrongly accused person. This is clearly ad hominem: an unfitting accusation, a personal attack, rather than reasoned criticism.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is *misunderstanding*. The interpretation is incorrect for the given context. 
If the last speaker is doing it intentionally to be troublesome then you could say they are *Spoiling for a fight*, trying to make trouble.

Answer (score 0):

*Person* here is ***misread***ing you (or your intention).

Lexico:

> ***[misread](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misread)***
>   *VERB*   [WITH OBJECT]
>   Judge or interpret (a situation or a person's manner or behaviour) incorrectly.
>
> ‘had she been completely misreading his intentions?’